# Background periodic task and notification showing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, notifications

I was looking online for the best solution but couldn't find exactly what I wanted.
So, I am developing an app using React Native, and trying to make it so that even when the app is closed, once an hour a background task (which will do some fetching) will run, and at the end of it a notification (not a push notification) with a custom message will show up.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you upfront.

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) which ships with RN.  For iOS you'll need a package like [react-native-background-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task), which works with both.  Android only projects you're probably better off just sticking with Headless.

Comment: How can I use that to pop a local notification (not push)?

Comment: I've never heard of a pop notification.  I think you described your issue very well, and if so, think of it as "pushing" a message from your app to the user's screen (with or without a background task).  Am I missing something?

Comment: I just mean showing a simple notification, with some custom text and icon to it... And doing that from the background task.

Comment: What I described are the two common ways of accomplishing that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [react-native-background-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task) to perform the task you wish like fetching every hour, and then using some notifications library(i prefer [firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/displaying-notifications)), you can show the notification to the user screen.
Also in firebase there is [scheduling-notifications](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/scheduling-notifications) with which you can schedule notification showing on the screen (maybe you find a use case needing it).